# Google Actions Home control sync response not accepted

Tags: actions-on-google, home-automation, google-smart-home

For the following Google Assistant Home automation sync request, my backend responses for certain accounts works. But some accounts it fails and I have no clue whatsoever.

```
{
    "requestId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "inputs": [{
        "intent": "action.devices.SYNC"
    }]
 }
```

How do I debug why a SYNC request has failed? Is there a console or log where I can see what went wrong.

Everything looks just fine. Similar response for some other accounts of my user base works, where as for this user's response it always doesn't work.

Not working Response:

In this instance, its failing for the following SYNC response.

`[{
  "payload": {
    "devices": [{
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:1:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Air Conditioner"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:2:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Office Hooter"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:5:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Office Motion"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:11:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Buzzer"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:11:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "DOOR SENSOR"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:11:4",
      "name": {
        "name": "Presence Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:14:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Blue Lamp"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:14:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Green Lamp"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:14:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Side Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:15:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Front Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:15:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Outdoor Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:15:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Front Dimmer"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:17:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Extra Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:17:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Central Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:17:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Fan"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:19:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Key Ring"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:19:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Office Door"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:19:4",
      "name": {
        "name": "Presence Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:6:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Blue LED"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:6:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Work Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:6:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Dimmer Back"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:4:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Buzzer"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:4:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Door Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:4:4",
      "name": {
        "name": "Presence Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:3:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Plug"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:7:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Curtain Up"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:7:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Curtain Down"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "7e-f2-ca-ab-40-34-34-95:7:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Regulator"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "27465191118001134545448968013",
      "name": {
        "name": "Darkness"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "27465189752942073090942148334",
      "name": {
        "name": "Everything"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "27507709627159036391184182205",
      "name": {
        "name": "Mood Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "27514704337364024105847592198",
      "name": {
        "name": "White Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "27576295525515559712639822299",
      "name": {
        "name": "Office Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }]
  },
  "requestId": "4881304563722779302"
}]`

---

Whereas for the following SYNC response, it works.

`[{
  "payload": {
    "devices": [{
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:1:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Serial Lights"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:2:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Water Heater"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:10:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Panic Alarm"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:11:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Hall Motion Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:16:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Buzzer"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:16:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Primary Door"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:16:4",
      "name": {},
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:6:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Car Keys"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:6:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Door Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:6:4",
      "name": {
        "name": "Presence Sensor"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:3:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Dummy"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:3:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "All Out"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:3:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Bed Room Fan"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:5:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Hall Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:5:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "Night Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:5:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Fan"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:8:1",
      "name": {
        "name": "Exhaust"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:8:2",
      "name": {
        "name": "kitchen Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "id": "21-0b-c9-87-db-70-b6-83:8:3",
      "name": {
        "name": "Balcony Light"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
      "willReportState": false
    }, {
      "name": {
        "name": "Good Night"
      },
      "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Scene"],
      "type": "action.devices.types.SCENE",
      "willReportState": false
    }]
  },
  "requestId": "13733611394224717847"
}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released a [smart home sync response validator tool](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/tools/validator/). Use this tool to validate the sync response that is sent to the Google Assistant.